# Can't remove the title bar and get transparency working at the same time

Tags: frame-parameters

In the never-ending quest to get a clean setup, I decided to remove the title bar from my emacs using the line

```
(setq default-frame-alist '((undecorated . t)))
```

However this seems to entirely remove the transparency which should be added by this line

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha-background . 90))
```

Not sure why this happens; does the transparency could as a window decoration? Not sure if anyone else has this issue. I would quite like to have both work if that's at all possible.

Comment: FYI, using your code, it works fine here (on Fedora + Gnome + Wayland).

Comment: Screenshot, plz

Comment: BTW, `alpha-background` doesn't work on some platforms (e.g., MS-Windows).